# Get Date time using GPS in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, gps, xamarin.android

I'm developing an application in Xamarin.Android where in I need to pick current date and time, Problem I'm facing is I need Date and time from GPS Location and not from Device.

So far I've written below code, but it displays date as January 1, 1970. 
What should I add to the code so that it'll display Current date. Kindly Help

```
Location loc = new Location (LocationManager.GpsProvider);
DateTime dt = FromUnixTime(loc.Time);

public DateTime FromUnixTime(long unixTime)
        {
            double seconds = unixTime / 1000;

            DateTime utcConverted = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,   DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(seconds).ToLocalTime();
            return utcConverted;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement [`Android.GoogleMaps`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/Android.GoogleMaps/), by which you can implement a [`OnLocationChanged`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.GoogleMaps.MyLocationOverlay.OnLocationChanged/p/Android.Locations.Location/) Method. which gives you a [`Location`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Locations.Location/). And the corresponding Location have a [`Time`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Locations.Location.Time/) property, which can give you Date and time from GPS Location